# Excel Script keeps giving error "Range merge: You cannot perform the requested operation."

Tags: javascript, excel, office-scripts

Ï'm writing an Excel Script.
Given a selected cell, it should:

- Insert a row below the selected cell (this works)
- For all cells of the inserted row which are in a column left of the selected cell, merge it with the cell above it (which is on the selected row). This fails.

The code is:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  const selectedRange = workbook.getSelectedRange();
  if (selectedRange == null) {
    console.log(`No cells in worksheet selected.`);
    return;
  }
  if ( selectedRange.getCellCount() != 1 ) {
    console.log(`More than one cell selected`);
    return;
  }
  // console.log(`Selected range for the worksheet: " ${selectedRange.getAddress()}`);
  // Insert a rwo below the selected cell
  const targetRow = selectedRange.getOffsetRange(1,0).getEntireRow();
  targetRow.insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down)

  // now merge each inserted row's cell left of the selected column with the cell on the selected row (i.e. the one above it)
  const sColNr = selectedRange.getColumnIndex();
  const sRowNr = selectedRange.getRowIndex();
  console.log(`col,row = ${sColNr}, ${sRowNr}`);
  for ( let c = 0; c < sColNr ; c++ ) {
    let r = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(sRowNr, c, 2, 1);
    r.merge(false);
  }
}
```

Problem:
I know I have the right cells in the for loop because I can set values in those cells.

Regardless what cell I select on an empty sheet, when I run the script,
the error msg I get is: "Line 23: Range merge: You can not perform the requested operation."

When I manually select the cells and use the Excel UI to merge the cells, it works.

I'm working of this documentation of Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel?view=office-scripts

Comment: Solved it. It's got to do with this operation not being supported on desktop excell. only on 365 online :-/

Comment: final working code on office.com/excel

Answer (score 0):

Range.merge() Operation is not possible in ExcelScript on desktop Excel...
It is though on office.com/excel.

Code had another tricky functional bug. solved that too.
Final code:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      const selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
      const selectedRange = workbook.getSelectedRange();
      if (selectedRange == null) {
        console.log(`No cells in worksheet selected.`);
        return;
      }
      // Insert a rwo below the selected cell
      console.log(`Selected range for the worksheet: " ${selectedRange.getAddress()}`);
       //get 1 based indexes of lower left cell of selection
      const sColNr = selectedRange.getColumnIndex();
      const sRowNr = selectedRange.getRowIndex() + selectedRange.getRowCount() - 1;
      console.log(`reference cell = ${sColNr}, ${sRowNr}`)
      const targetRow = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(sRowNr+1,0,1,1).getEntireRow();
      targetRow.insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down)
    
      // now merge each inserted row's cell left of the selected column with the cell on the selected row (i.e. the one above it)
      console.log(`col,row = ${sColNr}, ${sRowNr}`);
      for ( let c = 0; c < sColNr ; c++ ) {
        r = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(sRowNr, c, 2, 1);
        r.merge(false);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use in my automations.
If the range is merged, it will be unmerged and
if the range is already unmerged it reads this line, performs no actions and moves along to process the rest of the code.

// Unmerge range 13:18 on Sheet1

```
Sheet1.getRange("13:18").unmerge?.apply
```

In your case I would try this

```
r.merge?.apply;
```